# Unexpected inclusion of data in a String where it shouldn't be

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdatechooser

I am creating a Swing application using a `JTable` where you can enter a date and time into one of the columns. I am using `JDateChooser` and `JComboBox` drop downs which means I have to convert to String in quite a clumsy way:

```
Object[] row = new Object[2];

String Name = jTextField1.getText();

Object Hour = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
Object Minute = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
String Time1 = Hour.toString();
String Time2 = Minute.toString();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
String theTime = (Time1+ ":"+ Time2);
String theDate = dateFormat.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
String together = (theDate + " " +theTime);

row[0] = Name;
row[1] = together;

model.addRow(row);
```

The issue is that if I input "21.02.2019 20:00", the output will be "21.02.2019 00:25 20:00", and 00:25 is my system time. I had a separate functionality that read the user's time but even when I disable it the problem persists. I see no way for the system time to be output here, so anyone's thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: So you don't want the value from `HH:mm`? Why not just remove that part of the pattern?

Comment: What is the class of `jDateChooser1` (fully qualified class)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with this line:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
```

This line meant that the value received from the JDateChooser was received in the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm, which I didn't realize. To fix the issue I simply removed 'HH:mm' from the above code.